# Magento Password Reset Confirmation E-mail translation

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, localisation

I'm trying to create a Dutch translation for the Password Reset Confirmation E-mail.

**What i've tried so far:**

In the Magento folder structure, there is a directory holding all dutch e-mail translations: /app/locale/nl_NL/template/email/ however all my attempts to create a simular template for the Password Reset Confirmation E-mail are unsuccesvol.

[image: ftp screenshot]

Has anyone been able to make this work, perhaps for another language? Can someone please set me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you try copying `/app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html` to your `nl_NL` folder and translate it? You also can create a template in the admin backend.

Comment: Unless you plan to re-distribute your translation, just create Transactional email based on en_US version and then assign it where appropriate.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, this worked. If you post this as an answer i will accept it so others can learn from it.

Comment: I think you should always have a 'template' version of the email kept in the filesystem - the admin panel is for store owners to customise this default template.

Comment: Even if we create a new transaction email for PASSWORD RESET in the backend, there is no option to set the PASSWORD reset to that new file. How do you do it ?
I dont see any option for new registration and password reset options changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to copy `/app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html` to your `nl_NL` folder and translate it.

You also can create a template in the admin backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the Mage_Customer module.

In `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail`, the email is sent in the locale of the store that is associated to the customer instance by calling `$this->getStoreId()`. When the store is not set, the default store for the website to which the customer is associated is used.

In `Mage_Customer_AccountController::forgotPasswordPostAction` (the one place where this method is used), a customer instance is created based on the supplied email, but the store is never set on this instance. This means that email is sent to the default store of the website to which to customer instance is associated.

To resolve this, add the following line just before the call to `sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail`:

```
$customer->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

When you put this in an override of the original `Mage_Customer_AccountController`, the method looks like this (Magento CE 1.9.0.1):

```
/**
 * Forgot customer password action
 */
public function forgotPasswordPostAction()
{
    $email = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
    if ($email) {
        if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
            $this->_getSession()->setForgottenEmail($email);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Invalid email address.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
            return;
        }

        /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
        $customer = $this->_getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
            ->loadByEmail($email);

        if ($customer->getId()) {
            try {
                $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  $this->_getHelper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
                $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
                //START Set store id to fix email locale
                $customer->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                //END Set store id to fix email locale
                $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($exception->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_getSession()
            ->addSuccess( $this->_getHelper('customer')
            ->__('If there is an account associated with %s you will receive an email with a link to reset your password.',
                $this->_getHelper('customer')->escapeHtml($email)));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please enter your email.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to apply your suggest (Magento 1.9.1.0) but it didn't work (I have clear all "var/cache" before).

Comment: @KaMZaTA Can you check whether the controller override you have applied is picked up by Magento? You can do this by changing the overridden forgotPasswordPostAction method, for instance by adding a Mage::log statement.